# How can I find the smallest value in an array that is within an object inside of an ArrayList? The value is concatenated with other characters

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

I am programming a CPU scheduler for SJF in Java. I have an ArrayList that contains the job objects. Each job consists of a program ID along with an array of CPU bursts, etc. How can I find the smallest value, among all the jobs, that is selecting from just the lowest index of each array?

---

Okay, I will try to be more clear. Here is the code that I am using to create the jobs and add them to the ArrayList at the same time.

```
//add PCB objects to the jobQueue ArrayList. listOfBursts is an array.
 jobQueue.add(new PCB(processID, listOfCPUBursts));
```

Let's say I have 3 PCB objects in the jobQueue ArrayList. 
I need to run the CPU bursts in the order that they appear in the array, but the smallest value in the lowest index must run first. I feel like this is still not clear, so I'll try a picture.

```
          PCB-1's array = {4, 7, 2, 3}
          PCB-2's array = {5, 2, 1, 3}
          PCB-3's array = {3, 8, 4, 2}
```

These jobs need to go to the CPU, for whatever time-slice has been entered, and then returned to the jobQueue. The order that they go to the CPU needs to be determined by the lowest value that is at index 0 for any of the PCB's. In this case, I need to find the lowest of 4, 5, or 3.

Let's say the time-slice is 3. PCB-3 goes to the CPU, uses up it's burst then gets returned to the jobQueue. Again I need to find the lowest value to send to the CPU, but now I am looking at 4, 5 and 8.

I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide at least some code and an indication of what you have tried in order to get helpful answers. With what you have said here, it sounds like you would want a method that finds the lowest in the object and then a loop over the arraylist seeing if the lowest for the current object beats the lowest so far. But I'm a little confused by lowest index versus lowest value and what you mean about the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an Array to store all the lowest values from each CPU Burst array from each job. Initialize the size of this array to the number of jobs available (ArrayList size).

Iterate through the ArrayList so as to acquire each Job object stored there.
Acquire the CPU Bursts Array from each job and sort it in ascending order. This will bring the smallest value to the beginning of each array. Grab the value at index 0 and store in the array you declared earlier.

Now you have an array of all the lowest values.

Here is some example code:

> **The Job Class:**

```
public class Job {

    private int programID;
    private int[] cpuBursts;

    public Job() {}

    public Job (int programid,  int[] cpubursts) {
        this.programID = programid;
        this.cpuBursts = cpubursts;
    }

    public int getProgramID() {
        return programID;
    }

    public void setProgramID(int programID) {
        this.programID = programID;
    }

    public int[] getCpuBursts() {
        return cpuBursts;
    }

    public void setCpuBursts(int[] cpuBursts) {
        this.cpuBursts = cpuBursts;
    }
}
```

> **Fill The Jobs and ArrayList:**

```
ArrayList<Job> jobsList = new ArrayList<>();
Job job;

// Fill jobsList ArrayList with 10 different job objects...
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Create a new Program ID
    int id = 2230 + (i + 1);

    // Fill a CPU Burst array with 15 random integer values...
    int[] bursts = new int[15];
    for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        int randomBurst = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;
        bursts[j] = randomBurst;
    }

    // declare a job object
    job = new Job(id, bursts);

    // Add the job to the Jobs List
    jobsList.add(job);
}
```

Now you have an ArrayList named **jobsList** which contains 10 **Job** objects. Each Job object contains a integer variable named **programID** (which contains a unique Program ID number) and a integer array named **cpuBursts** which contains 15 *random* burst values from 1 to 100.

> **Now to get the lowest burst value from each Job:**

```
/* From the 10 Job objects stored within the ArrayList,
   display the all the jobs and at the end, display the
   lowest burst detected in each Job cpuBurst array.  */
int[] lowestBursts = new int[jobsList.size()];  // To hold the lowest bursts.

// Iterate through the Jobs within the ArrayList...
for (int i = 0; i < jobsList.size(); i++) {
    // Display information about the Job...
    System.out.println("Job #" + (i + 1) + ":");
    System.out.println("Program ID: --> " + jobsList.get(i).getProgramID());
    System.out.println("CPU Bursts: --> " + Arrays.toString(jobsList.get(i).getCpuBursts()));
    System.out.println();

    // Sort the cpuBurst array in ascending order.
    Arrays.sort(jobsList.get(i).getCpuBursts());

    // Grab the first burst within the array, it will be the lowest.
    lowestBursts[i] = jobsList.get(i).getCpuBursts()[0];
}

// Now, Display all the lowest bursts from each array..
System.out.println("Lowest Burst In Each Job:");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lowestBursts));
```